# AJAX request ot YQL, inserting Customer Key and Secret

Tags: javascript, ajax, yql

I've had some trouble querying Yahoo's API. While my code does work, it sometimes returns what I requested ( a stock quote from the financial tables), but sometimes the same query returns null results.

I figured I would register at Yahoo and I got my Customer Key and Customer Secret to see if that solves the issues of failed queries.

My question is: where do I insert the Customer Key and Customer Secret in my XMLHttpRequest (I am using standard JavaScript, not jQuery for the purpose of a project). 
Initially I thought that it should go in the GET URL:

```
?q=whatever&key=Mykey&secret=Mysecret
```

But putting a secret key in the URL makes no sense.
How should I proceed?